# QT + EGLFS issue during qt configure

Tags: qt

1. Host PC: Ubuntu 20.04
2. Target Board : BeagleBone Black (bone-debian-10.3-console-armhf-2020-04-06-1gb)
3. I’m trying to build qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1 for cross compiling BBB
4. I have rsync -avz debian@192.168.7.2: for sysroot with its libs etc
5. my configure command is
   sudo qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1/configure -release -eglfs -opengl es2 -device linux-beagleboard-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/BBB/tools/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/BBB/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5bbb -extprefix ~/BBB/qt5bbb -hostprefix ~/BBB/qt5 -v

6.and my config.summary for
QPA backends:
EGLFS … no

What do i do to get above EGLFS as …yes

Answer (score 0):

I have a manual which I've done for myself around a year ago. This describes how to cross-compile Qt for ARM based PC. My was Orange Pi. I am able to run QtQuck applications on that which are required EGLFS.

1. Download sources for desired version of Qt using Qt Maintenance Tool (there was some troubles with sources downloaded from web site).
2. Make changes in file `/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-arm-generic-g++/qmake.conf` with following:

   ```
   include(../common/linux_device_pre.conf)
   QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $${QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL}

   QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2   = $${VC_LINK_LINE} -lGLESv2

   # The official opt vc EGL references GLESv2 symbols: need to link it
   QMAKE_LIBS_EGL          = $${VC_LINK_LINE} -lEGL -lGLESv2

   QMAKE_LIBDIR_BCM_HOST   = =$$VC_LIBRARY_PATH
   QMAKE_INCDIR_BCM_HOST   = $$VC_INCLUDE_PATH
   QMAKE_LIBS_BCM_HOST     = -lbcm_host

   QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -march=armv7
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS

   DISTRO_OPTS            += hard-float

   EGLFS_DEVICE_INTEGRATION= eglfs_brcm

   include(../common/linux_arm_device_post.conf)
   load(qt_config)
   ```

Maybe on this step you can create your own folder like linux-bbb-g++ and put there files like in linux-arm-generic-g++ then specify this folder after -device key in configure.

3. Connect the sysroot from your board (I've been used sshfs not rsync)

   `sshfs -o idmap=user,follow_symlinks username@192.168.0.211:/ boardname`
4. Configure Qt

   ```
   mkdir build
   cd build
   ../configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -opengl es2 -eglfs -device arm-generic-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /tmp/orange -no-linuxfb -no-pch -reduce-exports -force-pkg-config -nomake examples -no-compile-examples -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebengine -skip qt3d -skip qtlocation -qt-pcre -ssl -evdev -glib -prefix /home/user/Qt/5.12.8/arm_linux_gnueabihf -no-use-gold-linker
   ```
5. Build Qt

   `make -j4`

Comment: Ok Thank you, i will try your suggestion and inform you.

Comment: Ok Thank you,  What does {VC_LINK_LINE} point to. In my qmake.comf i had mentioned as QMAKE_LIBS_EGL          = "-Wl,-rpath,${SYSROOT}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"                QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2   = "-Wl,-rpath,${SYSROOT}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"      but when i Configure Q i get                                                                                                 ERROR: Feature 'eglfs' was enabled, but the pre-condition '!config.android && !config.darwin && !config.win32 && features.egl' failed.

Comment: You don't need to change it. You must leave it as variable $${VC_LINK_LINE}.